# What makes a trade not eligible to update last traded price of a stock?

Tags: trading, order-execution

Hi I have below sample data for a stock.

[image]

Last column of data tells whether corresponding trade is eligible to update last price of stock or not. If 'Y' then it should update, else trade should be skipped. I don't have any other details about this data.
I want to know, in general (not specific to any particular exchange's rules) what could be the various reasons because of which a trade is not an eligible to update last price of a stock. I searched for any existing information on net but failed miserably.

Comment: Where is this stock listed? YESB appears to be "Yes Bank Limited", which is listed on the NSE (National Stock Exchange of India).

Comment: Yes, it is listed on NSE.

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: You could read the NSE rules (https://www.nseindia.com/regulation) and/or start a bounty for this question.